# Expected value of a product of 2 random multinomial variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, multinomial-coefficients

Suppose the following situation:

- We have $n$ marbles and these are tossed so that each marble lands in one of the $k$ boxes.
- The probability that a marble lands in box $\#i$ is
  $p_{i}\,,\ i=1,...,k\,,\ \sum_{i = 1}^{k}p_{i} = 1$.
- Then let $X_{l}$ be the number of marbles landing in box $\#l\,,\ l = i,j$. Define $Y_{l} = 1$ if $l^{th}$ marble lands in box $\#i,0$ otherwise. Similarly $Z_{l} = 1$ if $l^{th}$ marble lands in box $\#j,0$ otherwise.Here $i\neq j$. Also, write $X_i = \sum_{l = 1}^{n}Y_{l}$ and $X_{j} = \sum_{l = 1}^{n}Z_{l}$.
- Now follows a computation of $\mathrm{Cov}\left(X_{i},X_{j}\right)$ which ends with
  $=n\left
  \{E\left[Y_{1}Z_{1}\right]-E\left[Y_{1}\right]E\left[Z_{1}\right]\right\}$ and they claim:

"It is not hard to see that $E\left[Y_{1}Z_{1}\right] = 0$".

I do not understand here **why** ?.
To see the source type

"It is not hard to see that E" inference nitis

into Google.

Comment: If $Y_\ell=1$ doesn't that imply that $Z_\ell=0$ and vice versa?

Comment: Great, this follows...Thank you, that's my stupidity.

Comment: You **must** provide an actual link.  The result of a Google search will change over time as well as based on who is searching.  Case in point: this question is now in the top Google rankings for the phrase you give.  I don’t see any relevant matches when I try for myself.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've now obtained the right solution to my question by jjet.Thank you for your interest.

Comment: @ErickWong WHat Google says to you when you type that phrase into it?Does it or does it not show in whisper those words?

Comment: @user122424 I have no idea what you mean.  You claimed that the source can be seen by typing that phrase into Google.  My point is that is probably not true for everyone, and it is certainly not reliable in the future.

Comment: @ErickWong OK. I was just confused that on the one hand Google ranks it on the top, but on the other hand you don't see any relevant matches.Perhaps you meant **in the future**?

Comment: @user122424 This should not be surprising.  Google search results are not the same for everyone.  They probably depend on what country you’re in, your language setting.  Maybe they also depend on your search history and browser history, I don’t know.  The phrase you suggest is so generic that there are 100,000 matches, so it was an extremely unhelpful suggestion.  I was pretty sure that you were not reading a book on stable homotopy theory, but that was my top match!

Comment: @ErickWong I can see. But "nitis", the first name of the author, is not that generic as you claim, right?You're by chance wrong with the stable homotopy and me, though.There are plenty in our library and I've also downloaded some papers! By Goerss and others...But I do not see what is the best way to convey a pdf text to this site, can you advise me?

Comment: @user122424 Ah, I didn't see that was part of the search term.  I mistakenly thought it was some broken English phrase.  I retract my claim that the search term is unreliable (although I'll point out that the top hit is indeed your question and not the book) but I still maintain that a link is far more useful.  For instance you could have copied the [URL] from the books.google.com page.

Comment: So with the name "nitis" you can find the relevant page, right?I think that copying the link is still untransferable to others! There are cookies involved and so on.So how does one neatly/correctly/properly transfer a pdf page into math.stackexchange.com if one has pdf of the book in his computer?

Comment: @jjet Can you please have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605032/probability-of-tossing-marbles-covariance)?